# How to disable AVG Cybercapture

Tags: antivirus

I have a problem with my antivirus.
AVG added a new feature called Cybercapture which blocks every of my programs.
When I run my application using the debugger it holds it and then restarts.

It is really annoying.
When I tried to Google it I found only information how to disable AVG.

Do you have any ideas?

PS. I am using Visual Studio 15

Comment: In Code Blocks it is the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the same problem. I use Visual Studio 2017 and AVG 2017. If you want to disable AVG CyberCapture, you'll open your antivirus and click on settings. In General Options, remove the check at Active CyberCapture and you'll solve your problem.

Bye.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution:

[Click for Image Demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69BvQ.png)

Open AVG, and go-to the menu button on the title bar, then press "Settings", then select Basic Protection, then select Detections , Find a check Box of Enable CyberCapture Technology and uncheck it.

AVG -> Settings -> Basic Protection -> Detections -> Enable CyberCapture Technology

Answer (score 2):

Open AVG, and go-to the menu button on the title bar, then press "Settings", then where it says: "Enable CyberCapture", uncheck it or check "Allow me to decide".